# How do I delete all the entities related to a specific entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 and I want to delete all the entities that are pointed to by the navigation property on an entity.  How can I do this?

Comment: for some condition i need to delete a record from the application but it has lots of navigational properties associated with it, upto what i've done is delete all the navigational properties one by one.

Comment: Do you want to delete the *properties* or delete the *items* that the properties point to?

Comment: I want to delete the items that the properties point to.

Comment: @user1102482: I've edited the question to make that more clear.  Feel free to edit it further or roll it back and make your own clarifications if you wish.

Comment: @user1102482: Do you want to delete the original entity too, or just the items pointed to?  If you want to delete the original one too, then Eranga's answer is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve the problem in the wrong layer. You need to reconsider your database design specially how you maintain the referential integrity.

You need to set the "CASCADE DELETE"s of the foreign keys and reflect that in your Entity Model. Then the database will make the necessary changes to maintain the referential integrity when you delete that entity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood your problem. but as I know `.clear()` method clears and removes all the navigation properties like `Orders.clear()`

Comment: I've had `.Clear()` cause problems before because it will just set the related object's foreign key to `null` - this generally causes an error.