# Entity framework - deleting M row from an m:n relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I have AEntity and BEntity in M:N Relationship.

In the dababase I have 
     ATable,
     BTable, 
     ABRelationTable.

ABRelationTable is built as follows

```
Id                      Guid
ATableId                Guid
BTableId                Guid
AdditionalAttribute1    String
AdditionalAttribute2    String
```

I then delete AEntityInstance in EntityFramework and
It throws an exception then that it violates the FK in ABRelationTable

as follows:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_AB_A". 
The conflict occurred in database "X", table "ABRelationTable", column 
'Id'.The statement has been terminated.
```

How do I delete the corresponding lines in the relation table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the relationship has cascade on delete in SQL database table? If so you can do this in EF and it will be taken care of.
see...
[Entity framework - remove related records by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569504/entity-framework-remove-related-records-by-id)

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the associated `B`'s from `A`:

```
foreach(var b in a.Bs.ToList())
{
    a.Bs.Remove(b);
}
```

Or load `a.Bs` and `Clear()` it.

The point is that the `B`'s must be loaded first and then removed one way or another for the change manager to know that the associations are cut.